# The proportion of $\omega$s in $A$ converges almost surely to $P(A)$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

> Let $A$ be an event in $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. We generate independent inquiries from $\Omega$ in accordance to $P$. Show that the proportion of $\omega$s in $A$ converges almost surely to $P(A)$.

My attempt:

We define a random variable $\mathbf 1_A$ and let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of independent random variables distributed identically to $\mathbf 1_A$. Then $$\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\xrightarrow{\text{a.s}}E(\mathbf 1_A)=P(A)$$ Where the LSH represents the proportion of $\omega$s in $A$.

Would this work? Any improvements are very appreciated.

**Edit**: Here is what I meant: if we had $n$ experiments and in $k$ of them $\omega\in A$ then $k/n$ is the relevant share.

Comment: What does the portion of $\omega \in A$ mean? I have never heard this terminology before.

Comment: @Frank: it must be because of my poor translation. Please take a look at the edited post.

Comment: This confuses two situations: either one chooses i.i.d. $\omega$s from $\Omega$ and then the proportions of drawn $\omega$s in $A$ are random variables defined on $\Omega^\mathbb N$. Or, more classically, one draws once and for all some unique $\omega$ in $\Omega$ and uses it to deduce the values $X_k(\omega)$ of some i.i.d. random variables $X_k$s defined on $\Omega$. In both cases, the result you are interested in is most classical and called strong law of large numbers. Hence, at present, I am afraid there is no real question here.

Comment: @Did: many thanks for the comment, take a look at my attempt to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment made by *Did*, my confusion is somewhat cleared up now and I'll try to answer my own question.

We have $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ and $A\in \mathcal F$. Then $\mathbf 1_A$ is a random variable in $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$. We know that there is *another* probability space, let's call it $(\Omega_\infty, \mathcal F_\infty, P_\infty)$, and there is a sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ in the second space such that the sequence is independent and $P_{\mathbf 1_A}=P_{X_n}$ for the induced measures.

Since each element of $(\Omega_\infty, \mathcal F_\infty, P_\infty)$ represents a sequence of experiments on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$, $X_1+\ldots+X_n$ represents the number of the $\omega$s in $A$. Furthermore, by the strong law of large numbers: $$\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\xrightarrow{\text{a.s}}E(X_1)$$
We can't write $\bar{X_n}\xrightarrow{\text{a.s}}E(\mathbf 1_A)$ as I did in the post because $X_1$ and $\mathbf 1_A$ aren't defined on the same space.

But they are identically distributed, therefore $E(X_1)=E(\mathbf 1_A)$, and in turn $E(\mathbf 1_A)=P(A)$. Which is what we wanted.

I hope it makes more sense now.